How do I set up the model name using google's gemini AI?
I'm making a mistake setting up the model name and can't figure it out.
I'm using node.js.
My code:

const { TextServiceClient } = require("@google-ai/generativelanguage").v1beta2;
const { GoogleAuth } = require("google-auth-library");

  const aiClient = new TextServiceClient({
    authClient: new GoogleAuth().fromAPIKey(PALM_API_KEY),
  });

  const model = "models/gemini-1.0-pro";

  aiClient
    .generateText({
      model,
      prompt: {
        text: 'somePrompt',
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      //do stuff with the response
    })

Output
  Error: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: * GenerateTextRequest.model: unexpected model name format


  code: 3,
  details: '* GenerateTextRequest.model: unexpected model name format\n',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'

Documentation
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-ai/generativelanguage
https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/models/gemini#gemini-1.0-pro
I've tried each of the versions listed in the documentation and end up with the same error. What am I doing wrong?

You are not using the correct nodejs model.
You can follow the instructions from this Gemini API quickstart with nodejs
But basically:

the correct SDK package is @google/generative-ai
then on your code you will have the following declaration where you pick the model you want:

const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "the-model-name-here" });

Hope that helps.
